# Do people in the anime or manga actually eat Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon

In the anime, certain species of Pokemon are mentioned or depicted to be edible (by people or other Pokemon), like Magikarp and Farfetch'd.

[image: Magikarp Sashimi]

Do people actually eat Pokemon? If so, what other species have been mentioned or depicted as edible, in either the anime or the manga?

Comment: Out of all the questions I could have ever possibly imagined, I have to say this is by far the craziest. (And now, most plaguing.) +1 ^-^

Comment: [*Modern Farmer* makes a convincing argument about the food politics of Pokemon](http://modernfarmer.com/2014/05/food-politics-pokemon/)

Comment: In chapter 22, a human (Red) is almost eaten by a pokemon (Weepinbell) though.

Comment: they are non-Pokémon creatures in Pokémon because some Pokémon are called "cow Pokémon" and what not.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In November 2012, Game Informer got the chance to ask a long-time Gamefreak producer what the deal is with eating in the Pokemon world.

> **Is everyone in the world of Pokémon a vegetarian? Do people eat Pokémon? When they are eating steak are they eating a Tauros?**
>
> **Masuda**: There’s a lot of fruits and vegetables in the world of Pokémon. There is also a variety of snacks and various candies and whatnot that come from the different regions. The Pokémon world is much more technologically advanced than the world of our own, so perhaps there is probably a lot of different food that we can’t even think of.

Source: [Pokémon's Burning Questions](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/features/archive/2012/11/23/pok-233-mon-39-s-burning-questions.aspx)

Comment: A disappointing answer, but a definitive and official! Well done! +1.

Comment: In the game they do: https://www.polygon.com/2019/11/15/20963329/pokemon-sword-shield-slow-poke-tail-curry-sausage

Answer (score 48):

Some do, some do not.

It was mentioned by a developer once, that the Pokémon-world is better developed than our and most people are vegetarian. However, it can be seen, that some people eat meat, so I think you can say, that they eat Pokémon.

*The following did not happen in the anime, but in the Pokémon-world*

In the second generation of the Pokémon-Games (Gold, Silver, Crystal), Team Rocket sells tails of Slowpokes, which are a delicacy - That means that they're eaten, too.

Just to compare: In the anime, it's never shown, that Pokémon are killed, too - I think that's just because it's made for children ;).

Comment: The manga had a scene with a bunch of tail-less slowpokes tied up. Wasn't a pretty sight if you'd ask me.

Answer (score 27):

Yes they do. Just like in real world we eat some animal and we keep some as pets.

Edible pokemons : Basculin, Slowpoke.

**[Humans eating Pokémon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_food#Eating_other_Pok.C3.A9mon)**

---

> Meat is often shown in the anime, but while it has never been directly shown to come from Pokémon, no other food source has yet been explained. It is known that some Pokémon produce edible foods and by-products such as milk, nuts and fruit. These can be safely harvested with little or no harm or discomfort to the Pokémon. However, it has been mentioned that some Pokémon are hunted and used for their meat: Farfetch'd in particular are noted for making a good meal, especially when cooked with leek, and were nearly hunted to extinction because of this, ultimately leading to their rareness.
>
> During a story arc within the Gen II games and their remakes, the newly reformed Team Rocket begin stealing Slowpoke, cutting off their tails and then selling them as a rare delicacy. It is indicated that the tail is not eaten, but is sucked or lightly chewed on; similar to the manner in which a person would enjoy Honeysuckle.
>
> While visiting the Canalave Library, it is revealed in the Sinnoh Folk Tales that Pokémon caught from the sea are eaten, and then the bones thrown back into the water. It is also mentioned that the Pokémon that were eaten will return fully fleshed.
>   Ash and Brock imagining a cooked Magikarp.
>
> In Pokémon Shipwreck, Ash and friends, along with Team Rocket are stranded in the middle of the ocean without food. Eventually, due to their hunger and the dire nature of their situation, Ash and Brock began to discuss and fantasize about eating James's Magikarp. Unfortunately for them and Meowth in particular, Magikarp's body composition renders it nearly inedible. Misty elaborates on this, stating that Magikarp are nothing more than scale and bone, thus there would be little sustenance obtained.
>
> In New Plot, Odd Lot!, Harley has a flashback in which a class mate (who looks like May) stole his "snackie", which bore a resemblance to tiny Octillery, similar to the octopi served in some real-life restaurants. It is unknown if these were actual Octillery, or just food prepared and shaped to look like them.
>
> It is possible, based on wording used in Cherubi's Pokédex entry, that humans, not just Pokémon have eaten Cherubi's ball-like appendage before. Also, according to its Pokémon Black 2 and White 2 Pokédex entry, Basculin are remarkably tasty, indicating humans have eaten them as well.

Comment: Slowpoke tails were crazy expensive in the game.

Answer (score 15):

Well, this *is* a children's series. So I doubt actual Pokemon eating would ever occur in the series.

Though, it was shown once that Ash (even Pikachu) were eating meat once. Of what? Use your imagination :)

Answer (score 4):

I've seen Ash and Brock eat meat but I doubt its pokemon. I think the meat eating thing is to make it more relatable to real life but doesn't actually mean anything.

Answer (score 2):

From Chansey's pokedex entry!

> Chansey lays nutritionally excellent eggs on an everyday basis. The eggs are so delicious, they are easily and eagerly devoured by even those people who have lost their appetite.

So the reason Chansey is rare... People eat the eggs :o

Comment: So is Chansey a monotreme like Platypus?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but in the game "Hey, you Pikachu!", it shows Ash's mom cooking a seafood stew comprised of anything caught by the game player. Remember that this game was made for small children and featured their voice and microphone add-ons that allowed the child/player to 'talk' to a pikachu. I think that since Pokemon is Japanese based, eating 'seafood' pokemon was never deemed out of place. As for Misty down playing eating a Magikarp, she *is* a water pokemon trainer/gym leader and has an affinity to them. So her explanation could have been a bluff just to help save James' Magikarp from a gruesome end.