# Are Pokemon vegetarians?

Tags: pokemon

It is shown that Pokemon eat fruit, PokeBlocks or some random eatables. However, I have never seen a Pokemon being eaten by another Pokemon. Also, their trainers don't seem to eat meat. As there are only Pokemon in that world, eating fish would be equivalent to eating a Magikarp or other fish Pokemon.

Comment: Somewhat relevant: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/836/2604

Comment: Ash/Satoshi actually does eat meat in the first seasons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Horray for [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_food#Eating_other_Pok.C3.A9mon)!

The most commonly referenced mention of Pokemon eating other Pokemon is the entry about Pidgeot.

> "When they hunt, Pidgeot fly on the surface of the water at top speed to catch unsuspecting Fish element prey like Magikarp."

It is also referenced in Shipwreck, where Meowth attempted to eat James' Magikarp.

Farfetch'd also has an entry about how delicious it is.

The general consensus from my research seems to be that, while pokemon are likely eaten by other pokemon and occasionally humans, it is rarely if ever portrayed because Pokemon is aimed towards a child audience.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

It should also be noted that [normal animals exist in pokemon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Animals_in_the_Pok%C3%A9mon_world). There are multiple references to them, although they are rare.

> In both Raichu and Gastly's FireRed entries, Indian elephants are mentioned.
>
> In several of Bellsprout's Pokédex entries, Bellsprout is said to prey on insects.
>
> Victreebel is mentioned to use the Sweet Aroma of its honey to lure prey such as bugs, as well as large animals.
>
> Horsea is said to prey on bugs in several of its Pokédex entries. Some entries also mention that Horsea uses coral as an anchor to avoid being washed away, as well as for shade to build its nest in.
>
> Lickitung's Red, Blue, and LeafGreen Pokédex entries mention that it can extend its tongue like a chameleon.

Answer (score 2):

Numerous pokemons are stated as carnivorous, through generations. Some pokemons even use appearance as tool for hunting, e.g. Victreebel having shape of trap plant, or Mawile, having cute appearance in front to lure prey, and large jaws on back to grab it.

Comment: carnivorous is fine, but what do they eat exactly? other pokemons?

Comment: Yes, why not? Some even prey on humans. Also, i don't remember properly, if common animals exist in pokemon world, but if they do, they may be also eaten.

Answer (score 1):

The *Pokemon Alpha Sapphire* Pokedex entry for [Wurmple](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/265.shtml) states:

> Wurmple is targeted by Swellow as prey. This Pokémon will try to resist by pointing the spikes on its rear at the attacking predator. It will weaken the foe by leaking poison from the spikes.

And the entry in *Pokemon X*:

> It loves to eat leaves. If it is attacked by a Starly, it will defend itself with its spiked rear.

These two entries show us how Wurmple is targeted as prey by Swellow and by Starly.

While *Pokemon* is targeted a younger audience and darker subjects like death are almost always avoided, we can conlude that the pokemon universe is not too different from our own in that pokemon, like animals, eat other pokemon.

Answer (score -2):

In the games you make poke blocks out of berries ground together. Therefore I believe that they do eat vegetables but if Pokémon can kill each other in the Manga then surely they can eat each as wild Pokémon but I don't know of any certain points.

Comment: Can you include citations of specific chapters where a Pokemon kills another Pokemon?

Comment: I can cite from chapter 14 of pokemon adventures arbor was killed by blue's charmeleon